# Javascript / AngularJS object selection based on expression as key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a javacript object (basically, data coming from webapi call) in below format:

```
    $scope.Muncipalties = {
    "2290_BR1": "ABBOTTSTOWN",
    "2290_BR2": "ARENDTSVILLE",
    "2290_BR3": "BENDERSVILLE",
    "2290_TS01": "BERWICK TWP",
    "2290_BR4": "BIGLERVILLE",
    "2290_BR5": "BONNEAUVILLE",
    "2290_TS02": "BUTLER TWP",
    "2290_BR6": "CARROLL VALLEY",
    "2290_TS3": "CONEWAGO TWP",
    "2291_TS4": "CUMBERLAND TWP",
    "2291_BR7": "EAST BERLIN",
    "2291_BR8": "FAIRFIELD",
    "2291_TS5": "FRANKLIN TWP",
    "2291_TS6": "FREEDOM TWP"};
```

Now, I need to create another object from above one, however, it should be filtered by partial key value. i.e. say key is 2290 then only those records should be copied which has key as "2290_". If the key is 2291 then only last 5 records should be copied.

Is there any way in AngulaJS filter to do this?

Plunker is here : https://plnkr.co/edit/OmKHwF1fx1tUVVXYtogp?p=preview

Comment: thats not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for angular here, thats not an array its an object, to make another object do this:

[JsBin example](https://jsbin.com/futevu/1/edit?js,console)

Here you go:

```
var obj = {};

for (var prop in m) {
  if (prop.indexOf('2290') > -1) {
    obj[prop] = m[prop];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following code?

JS:

```
$scope.filterId = function(id, items) {
    var result = {};
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
      if ( key.match(id)  ) {
        result[key] = value;
      }
    });
    return result;
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(k,v) in filterId(2290, Muncipalties)">
  {{v}}
</div>
```